# AngularJS/Cordova/Phonegap Ipad 3 and Iphone 4s not fast enough?

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, angularjs, cordova

I own an AngularJS app (angular v1.2.19) that I converted into iOS app using Cordova/PhoneGap.
However, it seems that the `resolve` property (see below) is taking into account but the associated page is displayed BEFORE the promise is resolved, leading to some ugly flickering.
Flickering in this case is:  **the form only displays fieldset and legend + buttons for 1 second, and then the whole data (input etc..) are displayed.**

```
 $routeProvider
        .when('/page/meetings/123/edit',
        {
          templateUrl: "edit.html",
          controller: "EditCtrl"
          resolve: {
              activities: ['Activities', function (Activities) {
                    return Activities.getList().then(function(response) {
                        return response.data;
                    });
                }]
            }
          }
        }
      )
//page is displayed before activities are fully loaded.
```

Does a known bug regarding `resolve` property exist with Cordova? Or a configuration I should add?

**It works well in a browser**, but in the iOS app, I don't manage to make Angular resolve the promise before the page is rendered.
I don't figure out why this only occurs with iOS app and not web browser.
When I remove the `resolve` section, the page displays without flickering, although I don't have activities populated.

**Maybe just a performance reason?** Indeed, I tested the path `/page/meetings/123/edit` in my Ipad 3 (named "new Ipad") from a page where there isn't a lot of content, and it shows the page AFTER promises are resolved => fine.
The strange thing is that when I put the same link on a heavy page..listing several items, the targeted page (edit page) still flickers, displaying no form for about 1 second and then displays the whole.

To make things more strange, the exact same code on Iphone 4s involve flickers no matter where is the `/page/meetings/123/edit` link (heavy or light page).

On the contrary, web mobile version (Safari) on the iPhone 4s and Ipad is perfect. Really don't figure out why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some...hours of search, I found the reason.

In the edit page's controller, I initially did this:

```
$anchorScroll(); //scrolling to the top
```

It seems that it conflicts with the display of elements.
That explains why when I come from a page that needed scrolling (like 20 items in the list page), the conflict appears.

So the solution I choose is to do this, in order to delay the scrolling with the most minimal amount of time:

```
$timeout(
    function(){
       $anchorScroll();
    },
0);
```

The whole now works well with PhoneGap/Cordova for iOS app.